# Setando imagem em um botão utilizando o NetBeans 8.2

Tags: java, imagem, button

Estou tentando inserir uma imagem .png em um jbutton, eu coloquei a imagem em um pacote e to buscando elas com:

```
        btnCalcBanco.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        btnCalcBanco.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagens/Calculadora.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnCalcBanco.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 255)), "Calculadora", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BELOW_TOP));
        btnCalcBanco.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        btnCalcBanco.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(201, 131));
        btnCalcBanco.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(201, 131));
        btnCalcBanco.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(20, 13));
        btnCalcBanco.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCalcBancoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
```

Esse codigo é gerado pelo NETBEANS, quando mandei importar a imagem para o pacote,
já verifiquei o caminho da imagem e está certo e ate aparece na janela assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém quando mando executar o projeto ele da erro na execução esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se sua imagem está dentro do classpath da sua aplicação. Aparentemente está, dado que você consegue ver o preview dela na IDE.

Consegue fazer um teste e verificar se instanciando dessa forma funciona?

```
  JButton button = new JButton();
  try {
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/calculadora.png"));
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
  }
```

Esse código assume que a imagem estará na pasta **/resources/**

Comment: Tá retornando isso aqui java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Comment: Esse problema não me parece relacionado com o da imagem, consegue colocar um pouco mais do seu código e do stacktrace editando a pergunta?

Comment: Acabei de perceber um problema com a minha resposta e editei, o caminho esperado da imagem precisa de uma "/" no começo, e você pode ver o porque aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739550/difference-between-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-getclass-getres

Comment: como assim não entendi, aonde eu eu tenho que colocar o "/"

Comment: Era apenas a primeira barra dentro do argumento de getResource(). Eu acabo de criar um código similar aqui e aparentemente a solução funcionou sem exceções. Você consegue rodar um clean/build do seu projeto caso ainda não o tenha feito?

Comment: Consegui! o problema era que eu estava utilizando uma preview da pasta "java" porem o netbeans tava buscando na pasta "resource" ae ele estava me mostrando, porém na hora de executar ele não achava a imagem

Comment: Igor, você não deveria deixar perguntas "abertas", especialmente quando o problema foi resolvido. Você deveria aprovar uma resposta ou submeter sua própria resposta e aprová-la